# Showing data base on today's data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can I show a table of data that include name, gender, and DOB in a way that only it shows who is born on today's date?

Using java connection from jdbc.

ie. I have a table of 3 children born in 15/6/2015, 13/5/2015, 17/6/2015 respectively.

Only one children whose DOB was on 17/6/2015 (today's date) will appear on table after the logic had been executed.

Comment: Have you attempted to do this? If so can you show what you have done? You mention as well you are doing this from JDBC - could you show us your code/framework?

Comment: `if (year and month of birthdate = year and month of today) { born today } else {not born today}`

Comment: I will need to do a constant changing in my code. But is there anything i could modify my sql statement in which maybe i implement a timestamp?

Comment: what database it is? Oracle, MySQL, MSSQL etc. What is the data type of the column? Also important to know the table and other columns' name.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember of JDBC you can setup the query first, which in your case should be fairly straightforward. From there you just select the rows afterwards. Here is an example query you can work on.

```
SELECT name, gender, birthday FROM people WHERE birthday=CURDATE()
```

CURDATE() will give you the current date, and you can just compare it with the date of birth. If you require actual information on how to do this with JDBC - please specify that in your question, or leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

## Use A Decent Date-Time Library

You should avoid the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes bundled with Java. Instead use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later (inspired by Joda-Time). Code below using Joda-Time 2.8, and would be very similar if using java.time.

## Time Zone

Time zone is crucial in determining a date. For example, a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in does in Montréal. Most professional-grade databases store their date-time values in UTC time zone. You need to adjust based on your desired time zone. For example, if "today" in your app means "today in Montréal", then you must apply the "Americal/Montreal" time zone.

## Half-Open

Generally, the best way to handle a date-time range is through the "Half-Open" approach. This means the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This avoids problems like trying to determine the last fractional second of the day. Search StackOverflow for discussion and more examples.

## Date-Only

Perhaps you are using a `java.sql.Date`-compatible data type (a date-only value, without time-of-day) in your database rather than a `java.sql.Timestamp`-compatible type. If so, use the [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class in Joda-Time (or java.time).

The handling of date-time values is very limited in MySQL, so I'm not sure if this code example will work there. You may need to adjust. This example was lifted from my real work using [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) which has excellent date-time handling.

## Convert java.util.Date

If you need to convert the Joda-Time `DateTime` to a java.util.Date type for interoperability, then simple call the `toDate` method. The java.time package has similar conversion methods. Search StackOverflow.

## PreparedStatement

Strictly speaking, this example need not use a `PreparedStatement`. A PreparedStatement is needed if either (a) you will call this repeatedly and want a possible performance boost, or (b) you need to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security risks. Neither is the case here, but I find it easier to make a habit of always using a `PreparedStatement`.

## Code Example

The following example was never tested.

```
ArrayList< Person > list = new ArrayList<>( ); // Goal is to populate this List with Person objects representing rows from the database.

// Purpose: Query database for "person_" rows where the person was born today.
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime today = DateTime.now( zone ); // Get the date-time for a particular time zone.
DateTime todayStart = today.withTimeAtStartOfDay( ); // First moment of the day. Usually this is the time 00:00:00.000 but not always.
DateTime tomorrowStart = todayStart.plusDays( 1 );
// We will query by the "Half-Open" approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.
java.sql.Timestamp tsStart = new java.sql.Timestamp( todayStart.getMillis( ) );  // Convert a Joda-Time DateTime object to a java.sql.Timestamp object.
java.sql.Timestamp tsStop = new java.sql.Timestamp( tomorrowStart.getMillis( ) );
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder( );
sql.append( "SELECT name_ , gender_ , date_of_birth_ " + "\n" );
sql.append( "FROM person_ " + "\n" );
sql.append( "WHERE date_of_birth_ >= ? AND date_of_birth_ < + ? " + "\n" );  // Half-Open query, "[)", beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.
sql.append( ";" );
try ( Connection conn = DBHelper.instance( ).dataSource( ).getConnection( ) ; // Where "DBHelper" is your own class, to handle particulars for your own database, user account, password.
      PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql.toString( ) ) ; ) {
    pstmt.setTimestamp( 1, tsStart );
    pstmt.setTimestamp( 2, tsStop );
    try ( ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery( ) ; ) {
        int count = 0;  // Count rows extracted from ResultSet.
        while ( rs.next( ) ) {
            count++;
            // Extract fields from this row.
            String personName = rs.getString( "name_" );
            String gender = rs.getString( "gender_" );
            java.sql.Timestamp dateOfBirthTs = rs.getTimestamp( "date_of_birth_" );
            DateTime dateOfBirth = new DateTime( dateOfBirthTs , zone );
            // Instantiate an object to represent this row's data.
            Person person = new Person( personName, gender, dateOfBirth );  // Where "Person" is your own class for representing this data.
            list.add( person );  // Collect these Person objects.
        }
        // If expecting a certain number of rows, verify that number.
        if ( count == 0 ) {
            logger.error( "Found no row in database for date range: " + tsStart + "/" + tsStop + "." );  // I recommend SLF4J & Logback as a logging solution.
        } else if ( count > 1 ) {
            logger.error( "Found more than a single row (" + count + ") in database for date range: " + tsStart + "/" + tsStop + "." );
        }

    }

} catch ( SQLException ex ) {
    logger.error( "SQLException during: " + message + "\n" + ex );
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    logger.error( "Exception during: " + message + "\n" + ex );
}
```